# filter items from one column based on shared items in another R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table were each sample has a unique identifier but also a section identifier.  I want to extract all vs all distance comparisons for each section (this data comes from a second table)

eg table 1

```
Sample    Section
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         2
6         3
```

table 2

```
sample    sample    distance
1         2         10
1         3         1
1         4         2
2         3         5
2         4         10
3         4         11
```

so my desired output is a list which has
distance for: [1 vs 2], [1 vs 3], [2 vs 3], [4 vs 5]  - ie all distance comparisons from table two for samples which share a section in table 1

I started trying to do this with nested for loops, but it quickly got messy..  Any ideas of a neat way to do this?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Comment: ?? what is this

Comment: With the output from `dput(...)` we can reproduce your data, e.g. `dput(BOD)`. The data can exactly reproduced by `B <- ..... # (output from dput(...))` So, put the output from `dput(...)` in your question, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Alternative you can give a definition of your dataframe, i.e. `table1 <- data.frame(...)` .

Comment: ah clever OK noted thanks I will do in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

We can first create a data frame showing the combination of samples in each section.

```
library(dplyr)

table1_cross <- full_join(table1, table1, by = "Section") %>%    # Full join by Section
  filter(Sample.x != Sample.y) %>%                               # Remove records with same samples
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Sample.all = toString(sort(c(Sample.x, Sample.y)))) %>% # Create a column showing the combination between Sample.x and Sample.y
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(Sample.all, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%                     # Remove duplicates in Sample.all
  select(Sample1 = Sample.x, Sample2 = Sample.y, Section)
table1_cross
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Sample1 Sample2 Section
#     <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1       1       2       1
# 2       1       3       1
# 3       2       3       1
# 4       4       5       2
```

We can then filter `table2` by `table1_cross`. `table3` is the final output.

```
table3 <- table2 %>%                                     
  semi_join(table1_cross, by = c("Sample1", "Sample2")) # Filter table2 based on table1_corss

table3
#   Sample1 Sample2 distance
# 1       1       2       10
# 2       1       3        1
# 3       2       3        5
```

**DATA**

```
table1 <- read.table(text = "Sample    Section
1         1
                     2         1
                     3         1
                     4         2
                     5         2
                     6         3",
                     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table2 <- read.table(text = "Sample1    Sample2    distance
1         2         10
                     1         3         1
                     1         4         2
                     2         3         5
                     2         4         10
                     3         4         11",
                     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough this is a thing of great beauty - moral of the story I need to get better at dplyr!

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested to find all distance comparisons from `table2` for samples which share a section in `table1`.

This can be achieved by two different approaches:

1. Look up the respective section ids for `Sample1` and `Sample2` each in `table1` and keep only those rows of `table2` where the section ids match.
2. Create all unique combinations of sample ids for each section in `table1` and find the appropriate entries in `table2` (if any).

### Approach 1

#### Base R

```
tmp <- merge(table2, table1, by.x = "Sample1", by.y = "Sample")
tmp <- merge(tmp, table1, by.x = "Sample2", by.y = "Sample")
tmp[tmp$Section.x == tmp$Section.y, c("Sample2", "Sample1", "distance")]
```

> ```
>   Sample2 Sample1 distance
> 1       2       1       10
> 2       3       1        1
> 3       3       2        5
> ```

#### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
table2 %>% 
  inner_join(table1, by = c(Sample1 = "Sample")) %>% 
  inner_join(table1, by = c(Sample2 = "Sample")) %>% 
  filter(Section.x == Section.y) %>% 
  select(-Section.x, -Section.y)
```

> ```
>   Sample1 Sample2 distance
> 1       1       2       10
> 2       1       3        1
> 3       2       3        5
> ```

#### `data.table`

Using nested joins

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- setDT(table1)[setDT(table2), on = .(Sample == Sample1)]
table1[tmp, on = .(Sample == Sample2)][
  Section == i.Section, .(Sample1 = i.Sample, Sample2 = Sample, distance)]
```

using merge() and chained data.table expressions

```
tmp <- merge(setDT(table2), setDT(table1), by.x = "Sample1", by.y = "Sample")
merge(tmp, table1, by.x = "Sample2", by.y = "Sample")[
  Section.x == Section.y, -c("Section.x", "Section.y")]
```

> ```
>    Sample2 Sample1 distance
> 1:       2       1       10
> 2:       3       1        1
> 3:       3       2        5
> ```

### Approach 2

#### Base R

```
table1_cross <- do.call(rbind, lst <- lapply(
  split(table1, table1$Section), 
  function(x) as.data.frame(combinat::combn2(x$Sample))))
merge(table2, table1_cross, by.x = c("Sample1", "Sample2"), by.y = c("V1", "V2"))
```

Here, the handy `combn2(x)` function is used which generates all combinations of the elements of x taken two at a time, e.g.,

```
combinat::combn2(1:3)
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2]
> [1,]    1    2
> [2,]    1    3
> [3,]    2    3
> ```

The tedious part is to apply `combn2()` to each group of `Section` separately and to create a data.frame which can be merged, finally.

#### `dplyr`

This is a streamlined version of [www's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022678/3817004)

```
full_join(table1, table1, by = "Section") %>%
  filter(Sample.x < Sample.y) %>% 
  semi_join(x = table2, y = ., by = c(Sample1 = "Sample.x", Sample2 = "Sample.y"))
```

#### Non-equi self join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(table2)[setDT(table1)[table1, on = .(Section, Sample < Sample), allow = TRUE,
              .(Section, Sample1 = x.Sample, Sample2 = i.Sample)],
              on = .(Sample1, Sample2), nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>    Sample1 Sample2 distance Section
> 1:       1       2       10       1
> 2:       1       3        1       1
> 3:       2       3        5       1
> ```

Here, a non-equi join is used to create the unique combinations of `Sample` for each `Section`. This is equivalent to using `combn2()`:

```
setDT(table1)[table1, on = .(Section, Sample < Sample), allow = TRUE,
              .(Section, Sample1 = x.Sample, Sample2 = i.Sample)]
```

> ```
>    Section Sample1 Sample2
> 1:       1      NA       1
> 2:       1       1       2
> 3:       1       1       3
> 4:       1       2       3
> 5:       2      NA       4
> 6:       2       4       5
> 7:       3      NA       6
> ```

The `NA` rows will be removed in the final join.